# BufferedImage on SWT Canvas widget?

Tags: java, opencv, canvas, swt

Ok, I'm stubborn, I admit it. But...

I want to use canvas(or even label, doesn't really matter for me now) to show image in app window. But SWT accepts only and ONLY `Image` and after almost 2 hours now, trying few solutions, with http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ConvertbetweenSWTImageandAWTBufferedImage.htm on top of that and no luck. Is there any way of doing it without using utility like this? Trying to start with OpenCV already, so any way of converting `Mat` to `Image` would be also helpful.

Is there anything I can put here to help?
I'm using method below to get `BufferedImage`

```
public static BufferedImage mat2Img(Mat in)
{
    BufferedImage out;
    byte[] data = new byte[640 * 480 * (int)in.elemSize()];
    int type;
    in.get(0, 0, data);

    if(in.channels() == 1)
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    else
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;

    out = new BufferedImage(640, 480, type);

    out.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, 640, 480, data);
    return out;
}
```

and method from link above to convert it to Image. Still, it doesn't work and gives me an exception with(for me) unknown source. Code:

```
VideoCapture camera=new VideoCapture(0);
frame=new Mat(); //some are static
camera.read(frame);
bim=mat2Img(frame); //it's buffered image
im=new Image(display, AWT_SWT_converter.convertToSWT(bim)); //gives error here
```

and error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4422)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.init(Image.java:1943)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:453)
at com.ilmash.opencv.Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `bim` isn't `null`?

Comment: You probably need to show us the `AWT_SWT_converter` code because it is definitely returning null.